# Robot framework error connecting via telnet library

Tags: robotframework

Trying to connect to my remote host via telnet. Telnet client is enabled and running I get the following error:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encodings'
```

Find my robot code below:

```
*** Settings ***
Library  Process
Library  Telnet     terminal_emulation=YES      telnetlib_log_level=DEBUG

*** Test Cases ***

Try Telnet
    Open Connection     10.99.1.123     port=22
```

Am I missing something obvious here? Error really doesn't say a lot.

Comment: Is this working example of your testcase? At least *** Test Cases *** part is missing.

Comment: Just sloppy copying the example. It was always there

Comment: I do get the same problem while including terminal_emulation either in import part of Telnet library or in Open Connection keyword argument. If you do not need to use terminal_emulation (values should be set True of False as this is bool argument),just skip it.
As stated from Telnet libdoc and Telnet.py source,this document example returns your error :
 | Library     | Telnet    | terminal_emulation=True  | terminal_type=vt100  | window_size=400x100 |

Comment: error is thrown from: Python27/Lib/site-packages/pyte/streams.py ,class ByteStream, line 383 super(ByteStream, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) which calls parent class Stream at line 138

Answer (score 1):

Do you have latest version of pyte (pip list)? It seems that changes introduced in ver 0.6.0 breaks compatibility with Telnet lib.
If so,uninstall pyte,install pyte ver 0.5.2

```
pip uninstall pyte
pip install pyte==0.5.2
```

You can check release notes at https://github.com/selectel/pyte/releases